# Parse PHP comments for get meta variable

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using this `preg_match`

```
preg_match( '/^[ \S\t\/*#@]*'.$regex.': (.*)$/', $file_data, $match
```

to extract tags from 8KB of php file headers. For example, if I need to get value of `Some example` of the module from

```
/*
 * Some example: Lorem ipsum
 *
 */
```

`preg_match` will be like this:

```
preg_match( '/^[ \S\t\/*#@]*Some example: (.*)$/', $file_data, $match
```

and I need to get `Lorem ipsum`, but my `preg_match` doesn't work. Please, help me!

Full PHP source:

```
function get_module_data($path, $default_headers = ''){

    $module = fopen($path, 'r');

    // Pull only the first 4kiB of the file in.
    $module_data = fread($module, 4096);

    // PHP will close file handle, but we are good citizens.
    fclose($module);


    // Make sure we catch CR-only line endings.
    $module_data = str_replace("\r", "\n", $module_data);


    $all_headers = $default_headers;


    foreach ($all_headers as $field => $regex) {
        if (preg_match('/^.*?' . $regex . ':(.*)$/mi', $module_data, $match) && $match[1]){
            $all_headers[$field] = cleanup_comment($match[1]);
        } else {
            $all_headers[$field] = '';
        }
    }


    return $all_headers;
}
```

This function expect parameters:

```
/**
 * @param string $path path to file.
 * @param array  $default_headers must contain $key (name of parameter) with $value (Regex part without ":". E.g. 
 <code> 
$default_headers = array(
'AuthorName' => 'Author Name'
);
</code>
for search in file value of `Author Name: Lorem Ipsum` (will be `Lorem Ipsum`)
*/
```

Please, remember, that this function is a part of Izumrud System. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$file_data = <<<EOD
/*
 * Some example: Lorem ipsum
 *
 */
EOD;
preg_match( '/^.*?Some example: (.*)$/m', $file_data, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  * Some example: Lorem ipsum
    [1] => Lorem ipsum
)
```

Comment: I found this modifier, it's multiline mode, if someone don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the content from the php file you should parse it line by line,and if you find the * character at the begging of the line just use 
    str_replace("*", "", $string); 
And paste the specific line.

(On my phone right now,can't really write the code,but this should work quite well)